# If I want to be able to display the "total sales" within the file "Cart.txt", how would I do that?

Tags: java, file

I want the Cart.txt file to be able write whatever the total sales are in the file itself. The file right now just says:

```
3,2,Shoes
3,4,Shirt
2,5,Car
```

This is the current output:

```
run:
Enter how many items you are buying
3
Enter the items you are buying, structured as followed 
Quantity,Price,Item Name:
3,2,Shoes
3,4,Shirt
2,5,Car
Those values were written to Cart.txt
Sold 3 of Shoes at $2.00 each. 
Sold 3 of Shirt at $4.00 each. 
Sold 2 of Car at $5.00 each. 
Total sales: $28.00
```

This is the code itself:

```
package shop;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shop 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String fileName = "Cart.txt";
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;

    try
    {
        outputStream= new PrintWriter (fileName);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error opening the file "+ fileName);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter how many items you are buying");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner intinput = new Scanner (System.in);
    int input = intinput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the items you are buying, structured as followed"
            + " \nQuantity,Price,Item Name:");


    for(int count=1; count<=input; count++)
    {
        String line = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputStream.println(line);

    }

    outputStream.close();
    System.out.println("Those values were written to "+ fileName);

    try
    {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        String line = inputStream.toString();
        double total = 0;
    for(int count=1; count<=input; count++)
    {

            line = inputStream.nextLine();
            String[] ary = line.split (",");
            int quantity = Integer.parseInt (ary[0]);
            double price = Double.parseDouble(ary[1]);
            String description = ary[2];
            System.out.printf("Sold %d of %s at $%1.2f each. \n",
                    quantity, description, price);
            total += quantity * price;  

    }

        System.out.printf("Total sales: $%1.2f\n", total);
        inputStream.close();

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find file " + fileName);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem with input file " + fileName);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the following :

1. Write to the file after calculating the total :
   `outputStream.println(total);`
2. Close the `outputStream` after writing the total to the file

---

EDIT:

Make the following changes in this block of code :

```
    System.out.println("Enter the items you are buying, structured as 
                        followed" + " \nQuantity,Price,Item Name:");
    double tot = 0.0;
    for (int count = 1; count <= input; count++) {
        String line = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputStream.println(line);
        String[] arr = line.split(",");
        tot += (Integer.parseInt(arr[0]) * Double.parseDouble(arr[1]));
    }
    outputStream.println("Total sales: $" + tot);
    outputStream.close();
    System.out.println("Those values were written to " + fileName);
```

Here we calculate the total for all entries and then just write it once to the file.

Output

> 3,2,Shoes
>
> 3,4,Shirt
>
> 2,5,Car
>
> Total sales: $28.0

Comment: Yea I tried that already before, but the program runs exactly the same, and the file looks the same.

Comment: Why are you first writing to the file and then trying to read it?

Comment: My prompt wants me to first enter items like I'm purchasing something, store it to a file, and then display the items as well as the total. Then it wants me to write the total to the file as well which is what I'm having trouble with. I liked your response because I tried that too, but for some reason the total doesn't end up in the file at the end, only the original items.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a running total and then add it in at the end:

```
Double total = 0; 

for(int count=1; count<=input; count++)
        {
            String line = keyboard.nextLine();
            outputStream.println(line);
            String[] arr= line.split(",");
            total += (Double.parseDouble(arr[0]) * Double.parseDouble(arr[1]));
        }
outputStream.println("Total: " + total);
```

Comment: Sorry, I see someone just answered something similar.

Comment: The doesn't work :( because you defined count as a double and it can't be converted as an int and you also use it as an int in the for statement.

Comment: I know in your example you use integers as input. Are you allowing the user to enter doubles? I also changed count to total.

Comment: They can enter double for the prices only so it can be like: 2,3.50,Shoes for example. I'll try it with your updated code. Where exactly in the code should I place it? between what lines

Comment: it is the original block of code with added lines around it. Replace your for loop with this.